# Solution of transcendental complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, quadratics

I'm trying to solve this function

$$z^2 + 2z + 2\exp(-z) = 0$$

In one solution I found out the exponential function has been approximated to $\exp(-z)=1-z$, which makes it and easy polynomial to solve.

But is it the complete solution of this equation? Or are there better methods to solve this equation?

Comment: Of course replacing $\exp(-z)$ with $1-z$ is only an approximation.  Valid for $z$ near $0$.  So you only expect an approximate solution to the original equation.  And for solutions not close to $0$, this will not work at all.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8l-aI9pXVAhUn2IMKHcLSC0UQFggzMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLambert_W_function&usg=AFQjCNEBzIWUBjVKTwUKPhu9YXuMiprWPw

Comment: set  $$z=x+iy$$ to solve your equation

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Huh?  How in the world is this useful?  It hardly does anything to simplify the problem.

Comment: hm ok i will post it

Answer (score 1):

HINT: you will have
$$(x+iy)^2+2(x+iy)+2e^{-x}(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))=0$$
and you must solve the System
$$x^2-y^2+2x+2e^{-x}\cos(y)=0$$
$$2xy+2y+2e^{-x}\sin(y)=0$$
by a numerical method we obtain $$x \approx -3.293017589, y \approx 6.912667999$$

Comment: This seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Multiply both side of your equation
$$
z^2+2z+2e^{-z}=0
$$
by $e^z$, from which it turns into
$$
(e^{z/2}z)^2+4ze^{z/2}+4=-2(ze^z-2ze^{z/2}-1)
$$
i.e.
$$
\left(ze^{z/2}+2\right)^2=-2(ze^z-2ze^{z/2}-1)
$$
and starting from this, you can try to manipulate RHS in order to get something useful.